Find a datetime that works for everyone
Given a list of datetime ranges, write the shortest program/function/code snippet that returns a single datetime that is within all ranges, or some falsey value if no such datetime exists, i.e. a datetime that is in the intersection of the input datetime ranges.
Input
Input is a possibly empty list of pairs of datetimes. Each pair of datetimes is an closed interval from one time to the other.
Datetimes should be your language's native or stdlib implementation of a datetime. If no such datatype exists in your language, you may use any other reasonable input method.
Output
Output for given inputs should be exactly one of:

a single datetime that is within all datetime ranges in the input, or
a falsey value if no single datetime can be found.

The selected datetime should have second-level precision (i.e. units smaller than a second should not be considered).
Test Cases
Datetimmes will be formatted as YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS in these test cases. The given non-falsey outputs are just one possible output for the given inputs.
# [(start, end), ...] => output  # comments
# non-falsey
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/25 12:12:12)] => 2024/09/25 11:11:11
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/25 10:10:11)] => 2024/09/25 10:10:11 # closed intervals, with second-level precision
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/27 10:10:10),(2024/09/26 10:10:10, 2024/09/28 10:10:10)] => 2024/09/26 16:16:16
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/27 10:10:10),(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/28 10:10:10)] => 2024/09/26 16:16:16
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/27 10:10:10),(2024/09/26 10:10:10, 2024/09/28 10:10:10),(2024/09/23 10:10:10, 2024/09/29 10:10:10)] => 2024/09/26 16:16:16
[(0000/01/01 00:00:00, 9999/12/31 23:59:59),(0000/01/01 00:00:00, 9999/12/31 23:59:59)] => 2024/09/25 10:10:10 # both ranges are the same
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/25 10:10:10)] => 2024/09/25 10:10:10 # closed intervals, only one solution for this test case
# falsey
[] => falsey
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/27 10:10:10),(2024/09/28 10:10:10, 2024/09/29 10:10:10)] => falsey
[(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/27 10:10:10),(2024/09/26 10:10:10, 2024/09/28 10:10:10),(2024/09/29 10:10:10, 2024/09/30 10:10:10)] => falsey # third range does not intersect the other two
[(2024/09/21 10:10:10, 2024/09/22 10:10:10),(2024/09/23 10:10:10, 2024/09/24 10:10:10),(2024/09/25 10:10:10, 2024/09/26 10:10:10)] => falsey # all ranges do not intersect each other

Of possible use to you is Find the Intersection of 2 Sets in Unioned Interval Notation and Determine the busiest time.

A date can be represented as an integer (e.g. millis since unix epoch). Isn't this task therefore just to find an integer within the given integer ranges?

@noodleperson as noted in the Input section, you can use any reasonable IO format if and only if your language has no native or stdlib data type for datetimes.

As I see it, it’s arbitrary and unfair to forbid an answer from using a convenient input format just because the language supports other formats

Of course Swift's closed range intersection function doesn't distinguish between no overlap and overlapping exactly at the bounds.

May we take input as 2 lists? One containing the start datetime of each range, and the other the end datetime of each.

@Shaggy separate start and end lists are acceptable

Retina 0.8.2, 40 bytes
O^`
O`,.+
1G`
.+
$&;
O`.+?[,;]
G`;$
,.+


Try it online! Takes comma separated ISO local date time pairs on separate lines and outputs one of the date times or nothing if no valid date time can be found but link is to test suite which splits on semicolons for convenience. Explanation: Port of @doubleunary's spreadsheet answer.
O^`

Sort the date pairs in reverse, so that the maximum start date is first.
O`,.+

Sort the ends of each pair only, so that the minimum end date is also first.
1G`

Keep just the maximum start date and minimum end date.
.+
$&;

Append a semicolon if the input is not empty (to handle the special case of an empty input, which produces an empty and thus falsy output).
O`.+?[,;]

Sort the maximum start date and minimum end date.
G`;$

Delete the input if the dates were out of order.
,.+


Delete the minimum end date.

Vyxal, 4 bytes
ṡƒ↔h

Try it Online!
As per noodle man's comment, this is just finding a single value within all the ranges, if one exists (and Vyxal indeed does not have a datetime datatype). Returns 0 if it can't find one. Takes input as [range starts], [range ends].
ṡ    # Transform the inputs into ranges
 ƒ↔  # Take their intersection
   h # Take the first value


Google Sheets, 30 bytes
=(max(A:A)<=min(B:B))*max(A:A)

Put the start datetimes in column A, end datetimes in column B, and the formula in cell C2.
Falsey is represented by the dateserial 0. This value is shown as 1899/12/30 0:00:00 when formatted as datetime. To show FALSE instead, use if() (32 bytes):
=if(max(A:A)<=min(B:B),max(A:A))


